# Meteor call Email send from server returns fiber error

Tags: email, asynchronous, meteor, setinterval, fiber

I am trying to do something which i thought would have been very trivial, but apparently is not.
I need to do something very simple, I need to run a setInterval so to check whether "today" is a new day, and if it is a new day, get some data and send an email.

Everytime i try, it returns me the usual issue
 Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.
The code is running on Meteor server in a Meteor startup function.
All help will be greatly appreciated, i tried to solve it with async, fibers and future and i am either doing it wrong or i haven't found the answer yet.
Thank you, 
Alessio

```
setInterval(function(){
    var now = moment().format('L');
    var date1 = new Date(now);
    var date2 = new Date(yesterday);
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    if(diffDays>0){


        yesterday=now;

        //this is the part giving me problems
         Email.send({
        to: 'alexbonti83@hotmail.com',
        from: 'alexbonti83@hotmail.com',
        subject: 'test',
        text: 'test'
        });



    }else{
       // console.log('is the same day');
    }

},delay);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I may make a suggestion, you are better off running code like this through a backend cron job then through a `setInterval`. If your server is disrupted or restarts for any reason, the interval will be lost from memory and you are not going to get the expected behavior sending emails.

The package I use and like for this purpose is percolate studio's synced-cron: https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron

The answer to why `setInterval` is not working in your case is addressed in the Meteor documentation:

> Timers
>
> Meteor uses global environment variables to keep track of things like
>   the current request's user. To make sure these variables have the
>   right values, you need to use Meteor.setTimeout instead of setTimeout
>   and Meteor.setInterval instead of setInterval.
>
> These functions work just like their native JavaScript equivalents. If
>   you call the native function, you'll get an error stating that Meteor
>   code must always run within a Fiber, and advising to use
>   Meteor.bindEnvironment.